# Is there an ObjectMaterialized equivalent for complex data types?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to specify my DateTime values as DateTimeKind.Utc universally in my EF data model.  I've already found the solution to handle the data context's ObjectMaterialized event to do this for all entities, but this doesn't apply to the complex types that are automatically defined for stored procedure calls.  I tried using procs to fill entities, but that's not always possible.

Is there a similar handler I can use for procs that fill a complex data type?  I don't want to have to add manual date-fixing to every stored procedure result.